# iOS iPad Development Design Decisions

Tags: ios, photoshop

What is the best method to take a photoshop design and integrate it in xCode interface builder? Would i need to slice it and import the components into xCode or would I have to try and recreate the design from scratch in interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that someone has mocked up a UI for an iPad app in Photoshop, you'll want to recreate that interface with real components. You can do that with .xib files, storyboards, or in code. A button in a Photoshop document is just part of the image; in a real UI it's more than that -- it's a separate view that has state, can respond to messages, etc.

Images, whether created with Photoshop or some other editor, can of course be incorporated into your app and used for all sorts of things: backgrounds, button images, sprites, and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much ... Yes, a designer did mock up a psd for an iPad app ... I will have it sliced and incorporate the design elements as views, states, etc ... using the .xib files ... that will be used for button images, backgrounds, sprites ...

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If you don't use the system UI Elements at all, for example for a game, an approach similar to web programming (slicing etc.) might be fine.

If you do rely on system UI Elements however, I'd recommend using proper templates while doing design. There's a number of psd documents featuring those Elements out there which make iPad (and iPhone) design much more easy, [here's just one such site](http://www.web3mantra.com/2011/01/12/ipad-gui-psd-files/).